# c++ / difference between this and static class name

Tags: c++, static

One question according this code

```
Cl& Cl::getInstance()
{
    static Cl instance;
    return instance;
}
```

What do I achieve through this code and which difference would be if I would return `this`.

*this method is static

Comment: There is no `this` in static methods (I assume this method is static).

Comment: noone said it was a static method. It just returns a static variable.

Comment: pardon, I forgot to add, this method is static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is static, `this` is not implicitly defined, so the question doesn't apply.

On the other hand, if the method is a non-static member there's a huge difference.

```
Cl& Cl::getInstance()
{
    static Cl instance;
    return instance;
}
```

here you always return the same instance even called from several instances of the same class: a *singleton* (Misleading as the returned instance has nothing to do with the caller instance)

```
Cl& Cl::getInstance()
{
    return *this;
}
```

above, you're returning the current instance (not of great interest...)

EDIT: maybe your question is related to the [singleton design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) where no object can obtain a valid `Cl` object without using `getInstance()` because the constructor is private, and in that case, the interest is that it returns the same instance for every caller:

```
Cl& Cl::getInstance()   // static method
{
    static Cl instance;  // constructor is private, only can be called from here
    return instance;
}
```